# Error in Laravel installer by composer command

Tags: php, laravel-5, installation, error-handling, composer-php

When I try to install Laravel using composer by this command

```
 composer global require laravel/installer
```

I got error as:

```
  https://repo.packagist.org could not be fully loaded (Unable to use a proxy: mal
 formed http_proxy url), package information was loaded from the local cache and
  may be out of date


[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
 Unable to use a proxy: malformed http_proxy url
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Can you share more details about your configuration? How did you configure the proxy server you are using?

Comment: @Nico Haase 
require [--dev] [--dry-run] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--fixed] [--no-su
ggest] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--no-install] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-
dev] [-w|--update-with-dependencies] [-W|--update-with-all-dependencies] [--with
-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-
REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packag
es] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader]
 [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--] [<packages>]...

Comment: Please add all explanation to your question by editing it - also, this list of configuration options does not answer my question after all

Answer (score 0):

try in double quotes..

composer global require "laravel/installer"